# Who was the man in the Wayne building?

Tags: plot-explanation, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

At the start of *Dawn of Justice*, we see a flashback where Bruce Wayne was present in Metropolis while the highly destructive battle between Superman and Zod was happening at the climax of *Man of Steel.*  All over downtown, bulidings  were getting trashed, and a Wayne Enterprises building was right in the middle of the action.

We see Bruce Wayne on the phone with... someone... an older man in some sort of supervisory role, and he's urging the guy to evacuate the building.  But it's not particularly clear who the guy is, especially because it really sounds like Bruce is calling him "dad", but we know that his father is long dead at this point.  So who was he supposed to be?

Comment: At first I also thought Bruce said "Dad", but when he said it again moments later it sounded like "Jack".

Comment: Yes , he said "Jack"

Comment: I just came home from seeing this film and I recognized this "older" man talking to Bruce Wayne on phone as actor Lyman Ward (Ferris Buellers Father). But- he is not credited in film and I'm looking all over internet without results to confirm it was him.
Can someone confirm my finding? Driving me crazy!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [casting sources](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0536582/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t17), the man in the building is ["Jack O'Dwyer"](http://dccomicsextendeduniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Jack_O'Dwyer), played by actor Hugh Maguire.

[image]

Comment: Wondering why this got downvoted, as it contains a definitive answer with reliable sources.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers will not be of any use if the external linked page changes in future

Comment: @MasonWheeler - Because it doesn't show a link between the actor and the part.

Answer (score 6):

The man that Bruce was on the phone with was an executive in Wayne Enterprises. Presumably, he was the highest ranking executive in that particular building. When it sounds like Bruce is calling him "dad", I assume he's just calling him by name. IMDB's cast list just lists all of those people as "Metropolis Citizens", but I would assume his name just sounds like "dad" (e.g. "Dan").

Answer (score -3):

Jack O'Dwyer, played by actor Hugh McGuire.  I theorize he is the Wayne Industries Metropolis Division HQ's equivalent of Mr. Fox ... my 2 cents.